# Patch Upgrade or Patch Limitations on Developer Pro Sandbox?

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, developer

We have a special "Developer Pro" sandbox for doing some mobile app stress testing. This sandbox was created 24th of December. When we try to install a patch of our managed package (68.X or 70.X) we get this error:

```
Invalid Package - This package is not yet available. Please try again later or contact the package owner.
```

Is it possible that "Developer Pro" sandboxes are somehow configured differently in regards to upgrades? The 70.X patch was uploaded on the 18th of December (13 or so days ago). Also with the upcoming "Spring 14" sandbox preview, could this org somehow be cut off from new appexchange packages? Curious if anyone has insights on this or a similar experience.

Comment: Maybe your sandox is in API v29 (Winter 14) and your package from a dev org in API v30 (Spring 14) ?

Comment: Nope, both orgs are still Winter 14. After a few days of working through Partner support, R&D applied a patch which didn't fix it so they are still escalating. I think there is an issue with the cs20 instance.